# Creating plots for T periods Matlab to python

Tags: python, matlab, plot, time-series

I have this code from matlab that I am trying to translate to Python:

```
N = 75;
N1=31;
sigma_a=.08;
P0 = log(sigma/(sigma-1));
min = -.15+P0;
max = .15+P0;
P = linspace(min,max,N)';
e= linspace(min,max,N1)';
T=1000
      
plot((0:T)',[P(IndexP) e(Index_e)])
```

IndexP and Indexe are vectors of shape (51,).

I am struggeling with plotting this in python. In matlab the code is one line and creates time series from these vectors. When I plot in python I only get the length of the vectors in my plot. Any suggestions for python code on this?

Comment: Can you provide full matlab code?

Comment: Updated now. My code is very long and to retrieve the vectors I have to post a whole bunch of codes. However, they are vectors with 51 entrys between the numbers 12 and 17 for Indexe and 27 and 38 for indexP.

Comment: I wonder why `T` runs from 0 to 1000 but `P(IndexP)` and `e(Index_e)` are just vectors with dimension `51`? How can you draw graphs. I think it should be the same length?

Comment: I agree with you. I think the matlab code extracts the series into a time series or similar. But I dont see how this one lined code can do such wonders so I really wanted to try if it is possible to do such in Python as well.